# ++x++ не компилируется

Tags: c++

Почему это выражение не компилируется?

```
++x++;
```

Comment: A что вы хотите получить на выходе? это синтаксически неверная конструкция.

Comment: Наверное потому что это не предусмотрено синтаксически. А в чем его смысл? Я даже гипотетически предположить не могу, где такое может пригодиться.

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica почему?

Comment: @fool Не вносите крупных изменений в вопрос и не исправляйте ошибки в коде, после того, как получили ответ. Смысл стековерфлоу - создать базу вопросов и ответов. Если исправить ошибку в вопросе, то ответ будет выглядеть бессмысленным.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat ок добавил ответ

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Итак, приоритеты [операторов](https://ravesli.com/urok-38-prioritet-operatsij-assotsiativnost/). Постфиксный `++` имеет более высокий приоритет, потому выполняется первым. Но он, увы, дает rvalue - к которому префиксный оператор неприменим.

Поэтому нужны скобочки -

```
(++x)++
```

и все скомпилируется...

Comment: А если скобки поставить `(++x)++`? Всё равно не работает. Вот полный код `int x;(++x)++;int main() {}`

Comment: @fool Что значит "не работает"?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat не компилируется

Comment: @fool Потому что код должен быть внутри функции. `int x; int main() {(++x)++;}`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat так компилируется, а почему снаружи нельзя?

Comment: @fool Ну, потому что нельзя. Снаружи функций могут быть объявления переменных и разные другие вещи, но код (statement-ы) должен быть внутри функций. Какой-нибудь `std::cout << "Hello, world!\n";` тоже не будет работать снаружи функции.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat вот так скомпилировалось `int y = (++x)++;` нормально

Comment: @HolyBlackCat цаут тоже вынес вне и всё работает смотрите в вопрос код мой

Comment: @fool `auto& z = (std::cout << y);` - умно. :) Но работает только потому, что `std::cout << y` является частью объявления переменной (точнее инициализатором). Если написать `std::cout << y;` на отдельной строке вне функции, работать не будет.

Comment: @fool А нет, вы правы, из-за 4) и 5) UB тут нет. Извиняюсь, комменты удалил.

Answer (score 0):

Надо поставить скобки и будет работать:

```
#include <iostream>

int x;
int y = (++x)++;
auto& z = (std::cout << y);

int main() {}
```

Comment: Боже, до чего может доходить нежелание писать в теле функции...

Answer (score 0):

объяснение как работают префиксный и постфиксный операторы инкремента:

во первых, у постфиксного оператора выше приоритет чем у префиксного; постфиксный берет копию со старым значением и инкрементирует свое родное значение потом возвращает копию, которая является rvalue; префиксный возвращает сразу с увеличенным значением; логику этого можно увидеть в небольшом классе обертке над простым int c перегруженными операторами инкремента:

```
#include <iostream>

class Integer
{
private:
  int value;
public:
  Integer() :value(0) {};
  Integer(int value) { this->value = value; };

  // префиксная форма
  Integer& operator++() {
    ++value;
    return *this; 
  }

  // постфиксная форма
  Integer operator++(int) {
    Integer result = *this;
    ++value;
    return result;
  }

  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Integer& integer) {
    out << integer.value;
    return out;
  }
};


int main()
{
  Integer x = 0;

  std::cout << ++x << '\n'; // 1 
  std::cout << x++ << '\n'; // 1
  std::cout << x << '\n';   // 2

  std::cout << (++x)++ << '\n'; // 3
  std::cout << x << '\n';       // 4

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Только для вашего `Integer` выражение `++x++` будет компилироваться и работать.Чтобы добиться поведения, подобного "простым" типам, можно добавить ref-qualifier на префиксный инкремент: `Integer& operator++() &` тогда он не будет применен к rvalue-выражениям.

Comment: @Croessmah спасибо! получается как у меня работало без ref-qualifier, какое то не определенное поведение вызывало? там ведь не константная ссылка на rvalue возвращалась

Comment: префиксный инкремент требует, чтобы операндом был modifiable lvalue, но это относится к втроенным (built-in) операторам. К перегружаемым операторам же применяются  правила вызова функций: ```Overloaded operators obey the rules for syntax and evaluation order specified in [expr.compound], but the requirements of operand type and value category are replaced by the rules for function call.```